# Getting @permalink decorator to work with django generic views?

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

Maybe I am missing something, but according to the django docs (1.2), I have setup my URLS models exactly as specified to ensure I am not hard-coding urls returned for get_absolute_url.

Here's what I have:

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('django.views.generic.list_detail',
    url(r'^$','object_list',
            { 'queryset': product.objects.all(),
            'template_name': 'products/list.html',
            },
            name='product_list'),  
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$','object_detail',
            { 'queryset': product.objects.all(),
            'template_name': 'products/detail.html',
            },
            name='product_detail'), 
)
```

in models.py

```
@models.permalink
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('product_detail', (), {'slug': str(self.slug)})
```

The method returns an empty string in the templates, and from the shell it gives an error.

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'product_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': 'dd-d--'}' not found.
```

This should resolve should it not, since urls.py has a name : **product_detail**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax seems to be correct, are you sure your urls.py gets included? Try stepping in debuggin in view code and use *reverse* function first to generate the url.

My blind guess would be, something is wrong with your urls.py file in general.

Comment: yea, figured it out last night. Was not including it correctly in root urls.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this line:

```
url(r'(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/^$','object_detail',
```

to

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$','object_detail',
```

Carret (`^`) stands for beginning of the line, so it is illogical in the context you wrote it since it means the line has content before it even begins.

Comment: nicely picked up, made the change. However it seems it still cannot reverse the url.

Comment: I've tested the pattern and as far as i can tell it works ok, apart from that i can't find anything else missing.